# JSSOR slider in a lightbox

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am currently working on a project where the requirement is to launch an image slideshow in a lightbox when the user clicks on a link. What I've got working currently is a combination of featherlight and Jssor. When the user clicks on a link, I load a page with Jssor gallery in it. However, I don' think this is a neat/optimum way of doing things. 
What I would like to know is if there is a better way of achieving this? I guess I could write some javascript code and create my own version of Jssor lightbox. Not sure if already supports it or if there is a better way.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think you can load a page by $("#container").load(url); And you'd better call $Pause method before you unload a slider.